# WindowListener issue

Tags: java

I'm trying to add to my program a WindowListener but it's cant be done since i've got no JFrame in my GUI, instead my class extends JFrame.
anyone got an idea how to get through this?

Here's my piece of code which i cant make work since i've got no JFrame

```
  addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
   int confirmed = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
      "Are you sure you want to exit the program?", "Exit Program Message     Box",
      JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

if (confirmed == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
  dispose();
   }
 }
});
```

what should i write before the "addWindowListener" instead?`

[image: Here's the error i get in the compiler:]

Comment: Rather than `"which I can't make work since..."` -- **always** give us the full error message and full context. I have a feeling that you may be misinterpreting something.

Comment: I've added screen shot of the error due to your suggestion.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your class extending JFrame, or anything similar. Rather you're making a very basic Java error by adding that code naked in the class and not within a method or constructor. The only code that can be naked in the class like that are variable assignments. Java 101. In the future, please add the full error message -- much better as text and not as an image. This will avoid our wasting our time on wild goose chases.

Answer (score 1):

If you're within the JFrame extending class, simply add the WindowListener to `this`, the current object of the class. It looks like you're calling this within an anonymous inner class, and if so, then fully qualify your `this` with the class name:  `MyJFrameClass.this`.

So if your class is named `MyJFrameClass`, then

```
dispose();
```

becomes

```
MyJFrameClass.this.dispose();
```